# Is MoveToParent()/MoveToFirstChild() pair necessary with XPathNavigator?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, xpathnavigator

This is an example of using XPathNavigator from [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308343).

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;

// http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308343
namespace q308343 { 
    class Class1 {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            XPathNavigator nav; 
            XPathDocument docNav; 

            docNav = new XPathDocument(@"Books.Xml");
            nav = docNav.CreateNavigator();
            nav.MoveToRoot();

            //Move to the first child node (comment field).
            nav.MoveToFirstChild();

            do {
                //Find the first element.
                if (nav.NodeType == XPathNodeType.Element) {
                    //Determine whether children exist.
                    if (nav.HasChildren == true) {

                        //Move to the first child.
                        nav.MoveToFirstChild();

                        //Loop through all of the children.
                        do {
                            //Display the data.
                            Console.Write("The XML string for this child ");
                            Console.WriteLine("is '{0}'", nav.Value);

                            //Check for attributes.
                            if (nav.HasAttributes == true) {
                                Console.WriteLine("This node has attributes");
                            }
                        } while (nav.MoveToNext()); 
                    }
                }
            } while (nav.MoveToNext()); 
            //Pause.
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I think this code has a bug that it doesn't execute `MoveToParent()` to go up to one level when there is no elements to show.

```
nav.MoveToFirstChild();

//Loop through all of the children.
do {
    ....
} while (nav.MoveToNext()); 

nav.MoveToParent(); <-- This seems to be missing.
```

However, when I compile/execute this example, it works fine with and without `nav.MoveToParent()`.

Is MoveToParent()/MoveToFirstChild() pair necessary with XPathNavigator? Is it OK not to use `MoveToParent()` because the second execution of `MoveToNext()` works as `MoveToParent()` when the first execution of `MoveToNext()` returns false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code, after we go through all of the children of the root node, there is no more work to be done, there can't be more than one root node. So there is no need to `MoveToParent()`, we can just exit. Which is exactly what the code does.

Comment: And note that `MoveToParent()` won't always just move you straight back to the root, though-if you are in a child node of a child node, it will move you back up one level. This could be important/necessary if your construct is 3 levels: `<root><Cat1><One></One><Two></Two></Cat1><Cat2><One></One><Two></Two></Cat2></root>` where you need to traverse between Cat1 and Cat2 from within Cat1:One, but if you're just going from Cat1 to Cat2 in this construct: `<root><Cat1></Cat1><Cat2></Cat2></root>`, going to `<root>` again doesn't make any sense. You just do `.MoveToNext()` & then you're at the end.